# Launching Apache Spark SQL jobs from multi-threaded driver

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I was wanting to pull data from about 1500 remote Oracle tables with Spark, and I want to have a multi-threaded application that  picks up a table per thread or maybe 10 tables per thread and launches a spark job to read from their respective tables.

From official spark site https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html it's clear that this can work...

> ...cluster managers that Spark runs on provide facilities for scheduling across applications. Second, within each Spark application, multiple “jobs” (Spark actions) may be running concurrently if they were submitted by different threads. This is common if your application is serving requests over the network. Spark includes a fair scheduler to schedule resources within each SparkContext.

However you might have noticed in this SO post [Concurrent job Execution in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862956/concurrent-job-execution-in-spark) that there was no accepted answer on this similar question and the most upvoted answer starts with

> This is not really in the spirit of Spark

1. Everyone knows it's not in the "spirit" of Spark
2. Who cares what is the spirit of Spark? That doesn't actually mean anything

Has anyone gotten something like this to work before? Did you have to do anything special?  Just wanted some pointers before I wasted a lot of work hours prototyping.  I would really appreciate any help on this!

Comment: It is not in the spirit of Spark because the whole point of having a distributed worker pool is to leverage the worker manager to schedule the jobs on the cluster itself, not on the driver node. Why do you need multiple joblets/tasks per sparkcontext instead of multiple drivers and use normal abstraction (driver -> workers -> drivers -> actual workers)? Are you forced into yarn client or standalone mode for some reason?

Comment: Well actually at the current time yes I am forced into yarn client mode.  I'm doing everything with Zeppelin.  But even if I weren't, I would rather only have one artifact (one driver) since all of the jobs are doing the exact same thing.  At the very least, it would be an interesting test to see if the Fair scheduler handles the job scheduling better instead of me doing it.  Besides, as the Spark docs say, this is how network apps are run, and its not weird

Comment: I described the technique I use here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47733522/1138523

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The spark context is thread safe, so it's possible to call it from many threads in parallel. (I am doing it in production)

One thing to be aware of, is to limit the number of thread you have running, because:
1. the executor memory is shared between all threads, and you might get OOM or constantly swap in and out memory from the cache
2. the cpu is limited, so having more tasks than core won't have any improvement

Comment: The driver program won’t share an executor with the tasks.  The driver program is the one that will submit the spark jobs. This means the threads submitting the jobs won’t interfere with the threads representing the tasks. Also it does make sense to have more partitions to process than you have tasks, just make sure your executors are configured not to over schedule cpu and/or available memory. More but smaller partitions will result in better task distribution making sure that one executor suddenly does not have to process longer than another.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to submit your jobs in one multithreaded application (although I do see no reason you could not do so). Just submit your jobs as individual processes. Have a script that submits all those jobs one at a time and push the process to the background, or submit in yarn-cluster mode. 
Your scheduler (yarn, mesos, spark cluster), will only let some of your jobs wait as it has no room for all the schedulers to run at the same time based on memory and / or cpu availability.

Note that I only see benefit to your approach if you truly process your tables using multiple partitions - not just one as I have seen many times. Also because you need to process that many tables, I am not sure how much - if any at all - you will benefit. It might be simpler, depending on what you do with the table data, to have just multiple single thread and non-spark jobs running.

Also see @cowbert his note.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with @lev, I was wondering about it for a long time, So I wrote a simple small code to make sure it works, PLEASE NOTE!! in order to control the number of workers per driver you need to limit the dataframe/set with coalesce.

Here is the Example code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkMultiThreadExample extends App{

  val TOTAL_WORKERS = 10
  val NUMBER_OF_WORKERS_PER_DRIVER = 2
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  sparkConf.setMaster(s"local[${TOTAL_WORKERS}]")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
  val list1 = (0 until 10).toList
  import spark.implicits._
  list1.par.foreach(t => {
    spark.createDataset(list1).coalesce(NUMBER_OF_WORKERS_PER_DRIVER).foreach(i =>   {
  println(s"${Thread.currentThread()}, Driver thread ${t}: This is inside worker ${i} " )
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  println(s"FINISH ${Thread.currentThread()} Driver thread ${t}: This is inside worker ${i} " )
})
}) }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 0 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 0 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 5 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 0 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 5 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 0 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 5 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 7 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 7 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 4 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 9 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 4 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main], Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main], Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main], Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 9 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main], Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 4 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main], Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 0,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 4,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 3,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 7,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 1,5,main] Driver thread 0: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 2,5,main] Driver thread 2: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 9,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 5,5,main] Driver thread 3: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 6,5,main] Driver thread 5: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 8,5,main] Driver thread 4: This is inside worker 4 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 0 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 5 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 6 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 0 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 1 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 6 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 7 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 1 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 2 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 7 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 7 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 7 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 7 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 7 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 8 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 2 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 3 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main], Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main], Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main], Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main], Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 8 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 3 
Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main], Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 11,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 10,5,main] Driver thread 7: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 12,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 13,5,main] Driver thread 6: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 14,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 15,5,main] Driver thread 1: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 16,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 4 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 17,5,main] Driver thread 8: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 19,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 9 
FINISH Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 18,5,main] Driver thread 9: This is inside worker 4
```