# when to update driver resources

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

All,

Since the **driver** does not hold any data or process any data, *under what circumstances* would the default resources assigned to ***spark.driver.memory*** and ***spark.driver.cores*** need to be updated with higher values.

Can someone point me in the right direction with some links that I can read?

Thanks,
grajee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR answer** :

**spark.driver.memory** : When ever you are bringing data to driver. More specifically like a **Collect** or **Broadcast** operation

**spark.driver.cores** : After all  - driver process is either a Scala/Java/Python process. If you want to do some multithreading (like background process ) then you can use higher value for cores.

Comment: Sanket - Do you have a link that I can refer to?

Comment: Sorry nope. Just speaking from my experience. Can explain further for any of the cases.

Comment: 1 Example of Driver Cores requirement : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842048/launching-apache-spark-sql-jobs-from-multi-threaded-driver